# Rounding using uncertainty siunitx: uncertainty disppears if bigger than the main value

Tags: siunitx

I am using `siunitx` in order to display some "mean ± std" of some statistical results, and I use the `round-mode=uncertainty` option in order to keep the leading order of magnitude of the uncertainty only and match the precision of the mean.

However, if the uncertainty is bigger than the actual value, only a 0 is printed, without the ± sign or uncertainty.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{round-mode=uncertainty,round-precision=1,uncertainty-mode=separate}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\num{10.1 +- 1.0}   \\ % Correct output
\num{0.01 +- 1}     \\ % Prints: 0, should be 0±1
\num{1 +- 10}       \\ % Prints: 0, should be 0±10

\end{document}
```

Here is a somewhat [similar (unanswered) question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653180/rounding-to-an-uncertainty-larger-than-the-digits-with-siunitx).

Comment: This would be a feature request for `siunitx`: I guess you want some '`retain-...`' setting but don't have an immediate name for it.

Comment: (I feel the current behaviour is correct, but that's because the package is intended for formatting quantities and a quantity of 1 with an uncertainty of 10 is not meaningful, and would not use the `x +- y` notation for a mean/s.u. combo; however, the policy is I try to implement requests provided they are in-scope and have behaviour I can document.)

Comment: I understand your point of view, however, even for physical quantities it would make sense: p.ex. the difference between the expected and measured mass of an object. Such case could lead to a mass difference (with its units) that is smaller than the measurement uncertainty.

Comment: Also, any notation in the form of `x +- y` is a way to convey the centre and dispersion of a quantity, directly associated with its underlying statistics, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On reflection, it likely would be better to leave the uncertainty showing here for consistency with direct input of e.g. `0 +- 10`, then to look for an option to remove uncertainties which are larger than main value. I will address in the next issue-fix release.

---

The current output is by-design, but this could be adjusted by adding an option in this area. For the present, you could use

```latex
\cs_gset:Npn \__siunitx_number_round_uncertainty:nnn #1#2#3
  {  \__siunitx_number_round_uncertainty_aux:nnn {#1} {#2} {#3} }
```

which will bypass the test for sufficient significant digits in the main part.

Comment: Suggestions for an option name here are welcome: the code change would be trivial so easily integrated into the next release

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I'll try to think of a relevant name. I might appear quite ignorant (and I am...), but where/how should I use the option you mentionned?

Comment: @Mammouth I meant that I could add an option that would select between the two behaviours here (treating `0+10` as simply equal to `0` or retaining the uncertainty), but at the moment you can only achieve the effect by re-defining an internal function.

Comment: For example, one way would be to call the `round-mode` something slightly different, e.g. `standard-deviation` perhaps

Comment: `round-mode=standard-deviation` sounds good! Also, I realised that it is not possible to use `round-mode=uncertainty` with the option `drop-uncertainty` (I thought it would only prevent the displaying of `+- y` after having rounded `x`)

Comment: @Mammouth `drop-...` apply during parsing; `retain-...` during processing and `print-...` during output

Comment: My bad, it is really clearly written in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the update to the package, it works great ! A bit out of topic, but here is a feature request: it would be great to be able to center entries on the ± sign (without aligning the numbers on their decimal point, which can be unaesthetic for values of very different orders of magnitude).